# Are free modules injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and consider the category of $A$-modules. Let $F$ be free $A$-module. Then the functor $Hom_A(F,\cdot)$ is exact. Is the functor $Hom_A(\cdot,F)$ also exact? Equivalently, is a free module injective?

Comment: Just an easy comment: if $A$ is a field, then every $A$-module (i.e. $A$-vector space) is free, projective and injective.

Comment: Rings for which free modules are injective are called quasi-frobenius rings (noetherian self-injective rings).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I remember this: working again over $\mathbf Z$, we have a short exact sequence
\[
0 \to \mathbf Z \stackrel2\longrightarrow \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \to 0
\]
and it's clear that this doesn't [split](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Definition).

Answer (score 7):

Of course, $\mathbb{Z}$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module: it has basis $\{1\}$.

A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is injective iff it is a divisible abelian group (see [here](https://planetmath.org/AbelianGroupIsDivisibleIfAndOnlyIfItIsAnInjectiveObject)). This is a well-known result that gives a very simple characterization of injective $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module, since 2 is not divisible by 3.

$\mathbb{Z}$ thus answers your question negatively.

Comment: what is a divisible abelian group?

Comment: An abelian group $A$ (written additively) is divisible if for each $a\in A$ and each positive integer $n$ there is some $b\in A$ such that $nb=a$.

Comment: @Manos: I edited in a reference for the stated result. I recommend you learn it, it is very useful.